# Asylum and migration at the U.S.-Mexican border

Tags: united-states, immigration, asylum

The state of Texas has implemented measures to discourage or prevent border crossings outside the legal ports of entry.

I have a number of related questions regarding the border situation, which is why I ask them in one post.

1. Can a non-Mexican simply walk up to the U.S. side of a legal "port of entry"?
2. Because the U.S. officer there is on U.S. soil: Could they claim asylum there and be processed in the U.S. without being sent back?
3. If the answers to the above are "yes": Do illegal border crossings, e.g. across the Rio Grande,  indicate that the migrants do not intend to claim asylum?

Comment: I wouldn't count this as an answer, but [The US-Mexico border in a post-Title 42 world - The Take (podcast) | Listen Notes](https://www.listennotes.com/podcasts/the-take/the-us-mexico-border-in-a-7iSgf4LY2hT/), AlJazeera, dated May 18, 2023, talks, at fair length, about the US border agency trying to impose its smartphone app as *the* way to apply for asylum.  As in, "don't bother if not thru app".  Or maybe at least "try the app first".  Worth a listen if that's of interest.

Comment: Aren't the two first questions rather for https://law.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @J-J-J I wondered that, too. But some or most of the border situation seems to be defined by the executive (governor/president) rather than law-making, and in it all comes down to the third question anyway: Why do people cross in dangerous and illegal ways?, which is not a law question.

Answer (score 3):

> Can a non-Mexican simply walk up to the American side of a legal "port of entry"?

I find the phrase "American side of a port of entry" confusing, but perhaps this will answer the question: anyone who is in Mexico, regardless of nationality, can approach a US port of entry as a pedestrian (provided that the port of entry permits pedestrian traffic; not all do).

> Because the U.S. officer there is on U.S. soil: Could they claim asylum there and be processed in the U.S. without being sent back?

That is traditionally how it is supposed to work, but in the last few years US policy has been to make them wait in Mexico.

> If the answers to the above are "yes": Do illegal border crossings, e.g. across the Rio Grande, indicate that the migrants do not intend to claim asylum?

Of course not.  There are many reasons why someone who intends to claim asylum might cross the border outside of a port of entry.  The asylum seeker might believe that claiming asylum is not possible at a port of entry, or that attempting to claim asylum at a port of entry could result in being forced to wait for several months in Mexico.  These beliefs would influence the asylum seeker's choices whether they were correct or not.

Another point to be made is that the refugee convention explicitly contemplates irregular border crossing:

> ARTICLE 31. REFUGEES UNLAWFULLY IN THE COUNTRY OF REFUGE
>
> The Contracting States shall not impose penalties, on account of their illegal entry or presence, on
> refugees who, coming directly from a territory where their life or freedom was threatened in the sense of Article 1, enter or are present in their territory without authorization, provided they present themselves without delay to
> the authorities and show good cause for their illegal entry or presence.

It does not make sense to infer from an action that is consistent with this article that the person undertaking the action could not have intended to seek asylum.

Comment: Re "American side": That slipped, corrected. I'm not American (neither U.S. American nor one of the many other nations ;-) ) and find that usage sometimes confusing and often ignorant and presumptious as well.

Comment: Regarding article 31: Even though there is gang violence, Mexico is not a failed state and most people just go about their lives. I'd not consider Mexico a territory "where [the refugees'] life or freedom was threatened in the sense of Article 1", so the quoted Article 31 which demands "directly" does not apply.

Comment: And regarding the last sentence: "Does not make sense" is strong wording. If a person crossed the border illegally even though there would be a readily available legal route to entering and claiming asylum, it makes complete sense to assume that  they don't want to claim asylum. Now you made clear that the migrants cannot enter the U.S. legally during the asylum process. What happens if they cross illegally and then  claim asylum immediately, as it is their legal obligation, from (further) inside the U.S.? Will they be sent back to Mexico as well?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica my confusion had nothing to do with the use of "America" to refer to the US, which is in fact the most common meaning of the word in English.  I don't understand what you mean by a "side" of a port of entry.  Out of context I'd assume it means "the place you reach after being inspected and admitted" but that meaning is obviously nonsensical here.  Other possibilities I can think of are similarly inapplicable to this question, so I'm left wondering what it means.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica "directly" is of course subject to legal interpretation, but the general approach seems to be that the mere fact of transit through another country or countries does not deprive someone of the protection of this article.  See e.g. https://www.unhcr.org/uk/media/no-34-article-31-1951-convention-relating-status-refugees-dr-cathryn-costello-july-2017 "the Dutch Supreme Court held that the expression ‘coming directly’ includes people
who come to the Netherlands from another country where protection, safety and security
could not be assured."

Comment: Oh, I mean that a border is often guarded by *two* control posts: One on each side of the border. Often enough, the one on the "leaving" side is unmanned or even non-existing, because typically governments care less about people leaving than entering, but for example, when I crossed the U.S.-Mexican border towards Mexico  I needed to present my passport *on the U.S. side* because I needed the exit stamp. Therefore it is well conceivable that migrants would be stopped by a *Mexican* border post *in Mexico* before they reach the U.S. I meant to make that distinction.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica "If a person crossed the border illegally even though there would be a readily available legal route to entering and claiming asylum, it makes complete sense to assume that they don't want to claim asylum": it rarely makes sense to assume that you know someone's intentions.  There could be any number of reasons you've never considered that might impel someone seeking asylum to cross the border illegally instead of going to a port of entry.  "What happens if they cross illegally and then claim asylum ...? Will they be sent back to Mexico as well?" I don't think so.

Comment: @phooh ["Ah, this is obviously some strange usage of the word 'direct' that I wasn't previously aware of."](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/718.html) Also, I addressed "where protection, safety and security could not be assured".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148055/discussion-between-phoog-and-peter-reinstate-monica).

Comment: Non need to, I think we are clear.

Comment: "That is traditionally how it is supposed to work..." **Not true**. 'Traditionally', and according to international treaty (Article 26 - Geneva conventions), only someone who is directly leaving a country in which they are facing persecution can claim asylum at a border of a 'safe' country. Otherwise they are expected to declare asylum in the first 'safe' country they reach. If they are not Mexican, then the moment they approach the Mexican border, then they should request asylum there. If Mexican, then they should prove that they are facing persecution from the government of Mexico.

Comment: Note: That is not a hard rule. It's just how its always been until very recently for the United States. The UK has had issues for a few decades before then.

Comment: @ouflak the refugee convention says nothing about "first safe country" and as explained above "direct" is typically not interpreted to exclude transit.  Regardless, you seem to have misinterpreted the antecedent of "it," which is the procedure whereby an asylum applicant at an immigration checkpoint inside the US is paroled into the US for processing of the asylum claim rather than being made to wait abroad. Whether the safe country doctrine is relevant to the claim has no bearing on the procedure. "just how its always been until very recently for the United States": citation needed.

Comment: @ouflak Article 26 of which Geneva convention?  Anyway I did some research on the safe third country provision of US law, which was enacted in 1996.  It is [8 USC 1158(a)(2)(A)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1158#a_2_A).  It does not say "expected to declare asylum in the first 'safe' country they reach" but is rather conditioned on the ability to remove the person to (e.g.) Mexico, which requires (e.g.) Mexico's agreement. The 9th circuit's analysis: https://www.jurist.org/news/2020/07/appeals-court-rules-refugees-dont-have-to-be-denied-asylum-in-mexico-before-applying-in-us/#

Comment: @phoog, "That is traditionally how it is supposed to work...(for the United States)", "just how its always been until very recently for the United States". Curiously, I can't find any data online to support/refute *either* of these assertions. I expected to find a nice handy statistics document from the Department of State outlining number of Asylum claims by country by year. The closest I could find is this [2021 report to Congress](https://www.state.gov/reports/report-to-congress-on-proposed-refugee-admissions-for-fy-2021/).

Comment: There's obviously a surge in cases overall, but where those claims are coming from, I can't nail down. Maybe the OP can provide a link? I've never been great at Googling. I believe recently, in the last two years, claims have gone down overall. But again, I don't seem to be able to find a country-by-country breakdown versus that overall. I remember commenting on new articles regarding the surges in asylum claims at the border during the 20teens, but those are hard to track down. I might be wrong. Heck, I might even be spot on. Just can't prove it.

Comment: @ouflak If you google "asylum cases U.S. 2020" (or some other recent year, I tried 2019 and 2018), the first hit (for me) is a PDF from the DHS that appears to contain all the numbers. Given how bureaucratic data processing works (my guess: by manually entering numbers from faxes into Excel tables which are then communicated by phone, or the like) the most recent numbers are from 2021.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, That means I'll have to do my own compilation work though! Anyway, thanks. Maybe I'll see if I can pull some data together. I had the word 'surge' in my searches, and that was obviously messing up my results. Reading that first one (2020), it doesn't look like it will be easy to glean the data together to prove the OP's statement or mine. Not sure that project is worth it just to win (or lose) an argument on the internet. Can't believe, given how much attention this has gotten over the years, that nobody's already compiled this kind of data into a handy presentation.

Comment: @ouflak the data do not seem to indicate how the asylum applicants entered the US, however, whether by crossing the border illegally, applying at a port of entry, or entering legally with a visa, much less whether they entered through Mexico.  So it won't be possible to be very precise.  Regardless, we know the third-country principle did not apply before 1996 and the way it's presented in the current law requires an agreement with a third country to accept removed asylum applicants.  E.g. tables 17 and 19 at https://www.dhs.gov/immigration-statistics/yearbook/2019